# Magento 2 - sample data clean up script

Tags: magento2, php, database

I have been working on a Magento 2 site build and have the sample data-installed, which has been useful for layout and theme updates that I needed to make.

I would like to know if there is clean-up script/method available for removing Magento 2 sample data now that it has served its purpose.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Baber, found a solution yet? I am also looking for a way to clean up test product data (not just the sample data from Magento) So if you found a solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

There is a command to remove the sample data you installed before: sampledata:remove.

More information can be found in here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-other-cmds.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look at that over the weekend

Comment: Great, let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above and seems to get part of the way, it removes the json sample data entries and sample data modules from Magento2 but it does not clean up the database which what I am really after...